# Selling RSUs reported to IRS

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks

My company gives me RSUs.  These are heavily taxes (around 50%) at the time they vest.  I expected this to be my full tax liability for these RSUSI just received a 1099-B from the broker that handles our RSU plan.  It lists heavy gains for selling the RSUs I acquired.

Why is the money I sold the RSUs for (directly after they vested) taxed as well?  They did go up some, but nothing like what would require the many thousands of dollars TurboTax seems to think I owe.  Either I misunderstand RSUs and they're taxed twice, or TurboTax is waiting for some other form to show them that this income was from RSUs.  Which is it?

Comment: You voted your own question “close as duplicate”?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer - Yes, doesn't that imply to you that I found the other answer after I posted the question?

Comment: Sure, I just don’t see that very often. Common is that a member finds an answer elsewhere and returns to answer own question.